# How to simulate mouse movement and click on the particular cell in excel sheet

Tags: vb.net, forms

I am creating a script in visual studio express 2012 Form to open an excel sheet and right click on a particular cell (1,1). I know mouse click events and how to do it, but how will I simulate the mouse to move to the exact location of the cell (1,1).

This is what I am doing :

1. Form open a blank excel sheet
2. It add a number at cell (1,1)
3. Right click on the number at cell (1,1) (only mouse movement required, not keyboard)

step 1 and 2 I have done. But not able to complete step 3. Can any one help me ?

Comment: Why must you `simulate` a mouse movement? Why can't you just select the cell yourself by telling the excell reader where to go e.g `ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select`, this is of course if your using interop excel for reading a excel document

Comment: Issue is, there is an add-in inside the excel which take only mouse clicks. So even if i use ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1), and use keyboard keys to do right click on the cell, the add-in wont work. So this is the reason i want the mouse to move to that cell and perform right click.

Comment: Oh okay sorry you had no mention of that in your question. Give this website a look and into other API's which would help you with your mouse movement. https://www.vb-helper.com/howto_2005_mouse_move_click.html